# how to limit the size of a control to the size of the parent element?

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll, scrollbar

I have this xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Catalogo.Views.dlgGenerosContenidosAsignarView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
        Title="dlgGenerosAsignar"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        MaxHeight="{Binding AltoMaximoPermitido}"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        Name="ucPrincipal">


    <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,0" Name="lsbGeneros" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="130" Grid.Row="1">
        </ListBox>
    </grid>
```

I set the height of the window to the 80% of the height of the creen resolution, and the listBox can increase the height if I have many items. However the listbox increase the height without limit, so it goes out of the screen and the vertical scroll bar is never shown.

So I would like to know if there is any way to limit the height of the listBox to the height of the window, that is the parent control.

Comment: Your problem is *not* shown in your code. Your `ListBox` will have a `Height` of `200` pixels according to this code. Also, by default, a `UIElement` placed in a `Grid` *will* fill the size of that `Grid`, which if it is the root `Grid`, then will fill the size of the `Window`. Perhaps you have some code behind that you've not shown? If so, *that* is what is causing your problem.

Comment: There is nothing in that sample that reproduces the behaviour as @Sheridan also notes. Is it your Window that resizes, or only the ListBox? I note that you have SizeToContent set on the Window, which might bring you that behaviour.